# Scala libraries and frameworks

Tags: scala, frameworks

Each technology is powerful with libraries and frameworks, written for it. I understand, that Scala is able to use libraries and frameworks, written for Java. But there are already some frameworks, written for Scala in Scala. Like, for example:

- [Lift Framework](http://liftweb.net/)
- [ScalaTest](http://www.artima.com/scalatest/)
- [Scalaz](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)

Do you know any more great libraries and frameworks for Scala, written in Scala?

Comment: Agreed: it should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A number of Scala projects are announced on [implicit.ly](http://implicit.ly/), including libraries and frameworks; some are written in Scala.

Answer (score 6):

You should check out the [Akka Project](http://akkasource.org/). Among other things, it provides super-amped-up Actors as well as STM.

Comment: For the uninitiated, STM = Software Transactional Memory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out the [**Scala Bazaar**](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/93)? Or the Scala wiki has a useful page containing [search links](http://scala.sygneca.com/projects/start) to GitHub etc. One example is Paul Philips' [**Optional**](http://github.com/paulp/optional) library, the point of which, as I understand it is to declare a class:

```
class MyApp extends optional.Application {
  def main(i: Int, d: Double, os: Option[String]) : Unit = { /* App Logic goes here */ }
}
```

Which can then be run by:

```
java MyApp -i 1 -d 2.4
```

Or (as `os` is an *optional* argument)

```
java MyApp -i 1 -d 2.4 -os Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now a very good wiki about this subject: [Tools and Libraries](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries).